# ¿Por qué al intentar obtener el src del vídeo me suelta "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código que detecta automáticamente la dirección URL del vídeo. Sin embargo, cuando el código se ejecuta, solo muestra undefined. ¿Por qué?

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("video").src);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hola adios").src);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hola").src);
```

```html
<video controls class="hola" src="hola.mp4"></video>
<video controls class="hola adios" src="hola.mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque los métodos que usas: [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) y [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) devuelven un iterable, por lo tanto la propiedad `src` a la que tratas de acceder no existe en el iterable, sino en cada elemento del iterable.

Para acceder a la propiedad de los elementos debes recorrer el iterable (Ojo que **no es** un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) de Javascript. Es una lista de tipo [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)).

Por ejemplo:

```js
//console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("video").getAttribute('src'));
//console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hola adios").src);
//console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hola").src);

const videoElements = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

const classElements = document.getElementsByClassName('hola adios');

const classHolaElements = document.getElementsByClassName('hola');



for(let i = 0; i < videoElements.length; i++) {
  console.log(videoElements[i].src);
}

for(let i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
  console.log(classElements[i].src);
}

for(let i = 0; i < classHolaElements.length; i++) {
  console.log(classHolaElements[i].src);
}
```

```html
<video controls class="hola" src="hola.mp4"></video>
<video controls class="hola adios" src="hola.mp4"></video>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.